# AngularJS & Protractor - Make a http request last longer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, end-to-end

I'm working on tests for my angularjs app and when the page is loaded some http calls are made. When any call is made a loading circle appears and when a response is received the loading circle is hidden.

How can I make the loding circle visible for let's say 10 seconds ?

Comment: use `$timeout` service or `$interval`

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the http requests and delay them:

**network-delay.js**

```
exports.module = function() {
    angular.module('networkDelayInterceptor', [])
    .config(function simulateNetworkLatency($httpProvider) {
        function httpDelay($timeout, $q) {
            var delayInMilliseconds = 1000;

            var responseOverride = function (reject) {
                return function (response) {
                    //Uncomment the lines below to filter out all the requests not needing delay
                    //if (response.config.url.indexOf('some-url-to-delay') === -1) {
                    //  return response;
                    //}

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $timeout(
                        function() {
                            if (reject) {
                                deferred.reject(response);
                            } else {
                                deferred.resolve(response);
                            }
                        },
                        delayInMilliseconds,
                        false
                    );

                    return deferred.promise;
                };
            };

            return {
                response: responseOverride(false),
                responseError: responseOverride(true)
            };
        }

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(httpDelay);
    })
};
```

**Usage**

```
beforeAll(function() {
    var networkDelay = require('network-delay');

    // You can customize the module with a parameter for the url and the delay by adding them as a 3rd and 4th param, and modifying the module to use them
    browser.addMockModule('networkDelayInterceptor', networkDelay.module);
});

afterAll(function() {
    browser.removeMockModule('networkDelayInterceptor');
});

it('My-slowed-down-test', function() {

});
```

Source: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2802-simulating-network-latency-in-angularjs-with-http-interceptors-and-timeout.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of setTimeout method in javascript or alternatively $timeout function in angular js.

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout()` directly in your controller. If you use it then you need to trigeer `$apply` manually which is not good..

Comment: But I don't want to edit any of the app files, only the test files. So how can I set the timer to make the call longer when it is trigger when page is loaded ?

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to wait at least 10 seconds to fire your ajax call. You should fire ajax call at page loads and bind HTML after 10 seconds. It will work as you desire.